# How do you add -2 +2 options for code reviews in gerrit and require two to merge?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, gerrit

I couldn't find anywhere that would explicitly say how to do this. 
All I want is to create a project on github and set Gerrit up to have 4 Reviewers total on the project with the following rules:

You can either -2, -1, +1, +2:

A -2 means it cannot get merged.

A -1 just means theres something that the author needs to change

A +1 means it looks good but needs improvement

If two people who are not the code author +2 the code. Then it gets Merged.

I couldn't find where to add the -2/+2 options or where to add a rule that says there has to be more than one code review that upvotes it before being merged.

Comment: Sure of that ? https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-review-ui.html#reviewers

Comment: @pirs yes pretty sure. I have already gone through that link. Even the section you linked to is only talking about adding and removing viewers and the standard process that it already has built in. As stated by my question, I want to know how to change the way code reviews are done instead of the conventionally -1 +1 way. Thanks for the reply though

Comment: From the page `E.g. if a change requires approvals on the 'Code-Review' and the 'Verified' labels, and there is already a '+1 Verified' vote, then if the user is allowed to vote the max score on 'Code-Review', a Code-Review+2 quick approve button appears that approves the 'Code-Review' label if clicked.`
So, you have to go deep in the code because it seems to be not native